# Stata: order a dataset using a custom sorting order

Tags: sorting, stata

I have a dataset where numeric variable VARSORT takes only 3 values: 10, 20 and 30 (there are no missings).

I would like to sort observations based on VARSORT but where the custom sort order would be the following : 20 first, then 10, then 30.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Create an auxiliary variable that has value = 1 when `VARSORT == 20`, has value = 2 when `VARSORT == 10`, etc. Then `sort` by the auxiliary variable.

Comment: Note that within repeated values of `VARSORT` you will get a random sort order, and that may affect your ability to reproduce results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to sort on a variable with the desired order, which could be, among many other solutions,

```
gen varsort2 = cond(varsort == 20, -10, varsort)
```

There is no option to specify a custom order without specifying a variable. Clearly Stata has the idea that a dataset may be sorted by one or more variables. If that's so, then keeping track of such variables is crucial to Stata noting whether a dataset has changed (which includes a change in the sort order). That mechanism could not work in the same way if a variable or variables were not used to indicate sort order.